# SilverStripe 4.1 - SS_DEFAULT_ADMIN_USERNAME and PASSWORD not respected

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have a SilverStripe 4.1 site (upgraded from 3.4) running on an Ubuntu Vagrant VM. I have the following `.env` file:

```
# Default Admin
SS_DEFAULT_ADMIN_USERNAME="admin"
SS_DEFAULT_ADMIN_PASSWORD="password"

# DB credentials
SS_DATABASE_CLASS="MySQLPDODatabase"
SS_DATABASE_SERVER="127.0.0.1"
SS_DATABASE_USERNAME="user"
SS_DATABASE_PASSWORD="pass"
SS_DATABASE_NAME="silverstripe"

# environment
SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE="dev"
```

The site otherwise works, and complains when .env is deleted, so it's being read by the site.

However, when I go to `/admin` to log in with the above admin username and password the login page just refreshes with this message:

> You must be logged in to access the administration area; please enter your credentials below.

I've tried moving the .env file to different locations. Multiple `dev/build?flush=all`, a `flush=all` on the login page itself and manually deleting the silverstripe cache in `/tmp`. There are no errors on screen or in the logs.

Has anyone had this issue before, or can guess what may be causing this, or how I might trap any errors in a log?

Answer (score 3):

The issue was the client side cookies on the site. Something in the cookies must have been incorrect after the update, causing the log in to never go to the correct admin URL.

Using an incognito browser tab (or another browser) worked correctly, showing that the cookies needed to be cleared. I cleared my domain cookies and then the log in worked correctly again.